# Search specific value from a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a xml file with below content how to print only the `value='hard@insurance.com'` which is in row having `symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT"` using linux shell command in Ubuntu.

```
<entries xmi:id="VariableSubstitutionEntry_1468437285392" symbolicName="DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_NATIVEPATH" value="/cidba/udb/V10.5/java"/>
<entries xmi:id="VariableSubstitutionEntry_1468437302240" symbolicName="DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH" value="/cidba/udb/V10.5/java"/>
<entries xmi:id="VariableSubstitutionEntry_1468437322544" symbolicName="DB2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH" value="/cidba/udb/V10.5/java"/>
<entries xmi:id="VariableSubstitutionEntry_1503425349323" symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT" value="hadr@insurance.com"/>
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I am not able to print only the specific value from file.

Comment: You're not able to? So you tried something? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508512/shellscript-read-xml-attribute-value

So you can run this command:

```
sed -n '/<property symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT"/s/.*value="\(.*\)"[^\n]*/\1/p' /path/to/file
```

Comment: I tried above command its not working

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
sed -nE '/symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT"/s/.*(value="[^"]*").*/\1/p'
```

This `sed` command searches for every line containing `symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT"` and prints only the `value="xyz"` part of it.

#### Example run

I took your example here, so any typos are on you. ;)

```
$ sed -nE '/symbolicName="ROB_EMAIL_ALERT"/s/.*(value="[^"]*").*/\1/p' <test.xml 
value="hadr@insurance.com"
```

Comment: thanks guys i got the solution I use below to achieve my output.

Comment: sed -n '/<entries xmi:id="*"/s/.*value="\(.*.com\)"[^\n]*/\1/p'

Comment: @mrr That doesn't do what you asked for, neither the search nor the output match.

Comment: but i got the output using sed -n '/<entries xmi:id="*"/s/.*value="\(.*.com\)"[^\n]*/\1/p'

Comment: @mrr This searches for lines with `<entries xmi:id=""` in it and output only the address part of `value`. If you're preliminaries changed please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1003703/edit) your question and adapt it.